# Having trouble parsing complex json with Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am trying to parse the json of Riot's League of Legend, but I found out it's difficult for me since I am a beginner. Hope someone can help me out, many thanks. Here is a part of the json:

```
{
"type": "champion",
"version": "6.9.1",
"data": {
    "Thresh": {
        "id": 412,
        "key": "Thresh",
        "name": "Thresh",
        "title": "the Chain Warden"
        },
        "Aatrox": {
            "id": 266,
            "key": "Aatrox",
            "name": "Aatrox",
            "title": "the Darkin Blade"
        },
        "Tryndamere": {
            "id": 23,
            "key": "Tryndamere",
            "name": "Tryndamere",
            "title": "the Barbarian King"
        },
        "Gragas": {
            "id": 79,
            "key": "Gragas",
            "name": "Gragas",
            "title": "the Rabble Rouser"
        },
        "Cassiopeia": {
            "id": 69,
            "key": "Cassiopeia",
            "name": "Cassiopeia",
            "title": "the Serpent's Embrace"
        },
        "AurelionSol": {
            "id": 136,
            "key": "AurelionSol",
            "name": "Aurelion Sol",
            "title": "The Star Forger"
        },
        "Ryze": {
            "id": 13,
            "key": "Ryze",
            "name": "Ryze",
            "title": "the Rogue Mage"
        },
        "Poppy": {
            "id": 78,
            "key": "Poppy",
            "name": "Poppy",
            "title": "Keeper of the Hammer"
        },
        "Sion": {
            "id": 14,
            "key": "Sion",
            "name": "Sion",
            "title": "The Undead Juggernaut"
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Should I declare a class for each champion(which means I have to declare over one hundred classes), or is there a simple way to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your model generic for this i would recommend to read about generic programming. Use this [link](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c10/s5.html#generics.5.1) as a reading material

Use `jsontopojo` a web tool. Just to go this site. Past your valid json and it will produces classes itself. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Note: You gotta select JSON as source type in the web tool.